# The set of zero measure from Zorich's book

Tags: real-analysis

This is actually from Zurich's book (chapter on Integration).

> **Definition.** A set $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ *has measure zero* or *is of measure zero* (in the sense of Lebesgue) if for every number
> $\epsilon>0$ there exists a covering of the set $E$ by an at most
> countable system $\{I_k\}$ of intervals, the sum of whose lengths
> $\sum \limits_{k=1}|I_k|$ is at most $\epsilon$.
>
> **Lemma.** *The union of a finite or countable number of sets of measure zero is a set of measure zero.*

*Proof:* Suppose that $E=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ and each $E_n$ has measure zero. Suppose $\epsilon>0$ be given. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ by definition we can find an at most  countable system $\{I_{n,k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ of intervals such that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|I_{n,k}|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2^n}$.

Then we see that $\{I_{n,k}: n,k\geq 1\}$ be a countable system of intervals covering $E$.

How formally to show that total length of these $I_{n,k}$ is less than $\epsilon$?

Because if we want to compute its total length then we need to deal with the double sum $\sum \limits_{n,k\geq 1}$ or $\sum \limits_{n\geq 1} \sum \limits_{k\geq 1}
$ (btw I don't know the difference between them).

I would be very thankful if someone can show the formal proof of it please!

Comment: This is a fact about series, double series, etc. of positive numbers that probably should be mentioned when it first arises, such as in this case. See Article 31 (pp. 82-85) in [**An Introduction to the Theory of Infinite Series**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.233335/page/n99/mode/2up) by Bromwich (1925 2nd edition), a book I mention because it will serve to answer most any series question you might ever have now or later.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, sorry but can you explain my question, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Zorich is super clear on this point. The closest he comes to an explanation is this:

> The order of summation $\sum_{n,k} |I^n_k|$ on the indices $n$ and $k$ is of no importance, since the series converges to the same sum for any order of summation if it converges in even one ordering. [Zorich is referring to Proposition 4, page 270.] Such is the case here, since any partial terms of the sum are bounded above by $\varepsilon$.

I would explain this this way. Let $a_n = \sum_{k} |I^n_k| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}$. Now let $A = \sum_{j=1}^J |I^{n_j}_{k_j}|$ be any partial sum of the series $\sum_{n,k} |I^n_k|$ arranged in an arbitrary order. If we let $N = \max_j n_j$, then $A \leq \sum_{n = 1}^N a_n \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} a_n$.

Since any partial sum of the series $\sum_{n,k} |I^n_k|$ is $\leq \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} a_n$, we have
$$
\sum_{n,k} |I^n_k| \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} a_n < \varepsilon.
$$

It's true there are theorems about double series that would make the original claim obvious, but you can get by without them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but let me ask you a question please: what is the definition of $\sum_{n,k}|I_k^n|$? It is a double summation so we have to define it somehow before doing any manipulations with it.

Comment: Zorich answers this in the text: the index set (of all pairs $(n,k)$) is countable. Therefore, select one ordering of the index set to define the meaning of the series. If the series is convergent for one ordering, it is convergent for any other ordering, with the same sum. This follows from Proposition 4 on page 270 and the fact that the terms are nonnegative. Hence the series has a meaning independent of any particular ordering.

Comment: Yeah, your reasoning looks really rigorous and convincing! Let me ask you a question please: So you basically fix some order of summation in $\sum \limits_{n,k}|I_k^n|$ and then you show that its partial sum are bounded and since terms are $\geq 0$ then it converges. Hence by Proposition 4(page 270) it converges for any other summation, right?

Comment: Yes, but you need more than that. You need to show that its partial sums are bounded by some number strictly less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Okay, maybe you're still asking about the definition of the series. Even before you check that the partial sums are bounded, you know that the series either converges or diverges to $+\infty$, and that if you reorder it, you will get the same sum (which could be $+\infty$). In my mind, checking that the partial sums were bounded by a number smaller than $\varepsilon$ was the next step.

Comment: Right now I am more confused than before. Can you explain what do you mean? It would be great if you can add it in your answer.

Comment: You want to say that $\sum_{(n,k)} |I^n_k|$ is meaningful (either as a finite number or $+\infty$), but you also want to show that it is $< \varepsilon$. The first part has nothing to do with $\varepsilon$, but the second part is needed in order to complete Zorich's argument.

Comment: I am really confused. You really confused me. Can you give a more detailed answer?

Comment: @PlayGame The quote from the book explains why the sum of the series $\sum_{n,k} |I^n_k|$ is well-defined (with a finite or infinite sum). The part of the answer that I wrote explains in greater detail why the sum is finite and $< \varepsilon$, which is what needs to be proved. I'm sorry, but if you don't have a more specific question, I don't wish to go into greater detail than I already have.

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that you don't actually need to compute it.  What you do is for your first set,  $E_1$,  choose a covering so that the total measure is less than $\frac \epsilon 2$.  The second set you choose one whose total is less than $\frac \epsilon 4$,   then $n'th$ one a cover whose total length is less than $\frac \epsilon {2^n}$.   Now,   taking the union and all you have is the simple geometric series $\frac \epsilon {2^n}$,  which adds up to $\epsilon$

Edited to add complicated notation:

For Set $E_1$  choose a covering $E_{1,k}$  such that $\sum_{k\geq 1}E_{1,k}<\frac \epsilon 2$.   Similarly, for each set $E_n$ choose a covering so that $\sum_{k\geq 1}E_{n,k}<\frac \epsilon {2^n}$

Now,  $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}E_n $is covered by $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq 1}E_{n,k}$,  and taking the sum of the lengths,  we have the union is less than

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{k\geq 1}E_{n,k}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}E_{n,k}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac \epsilon {2^n}=\epsilon $$

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply! But I don't find a rigorous. Can you give more details?

Comment: All I did was skip the sigma notation, but I can add it.

Comment: @PlayGame Notation added

Comment: It looks better but still why the formula in the last line makes sense? Still I don't find that answer rigorous and has some small mistakes in notations.

Comment: Do you get that set $E_n$ has a covering $E_{n,k}$ such that the total length is less than $\sum_{k\geq 1}E_{n,k}<\frac \epsilon {2^n}$?

Comment: Yes I do. I understand that moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128909/discussion-between-alan-and-playgame).